# Simulate 4 quadrants with array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting, data-structures

I am creating an app using C# that builds objects and moves them in different positions on a Cartesian plane. I start with the first object at position (0,0). I figured I could represent this in a 2D array, but how should I go about representing an object at position (-x,y), (-x,-y,) or (x,-y)?

Right now I'm thinking of using four arrays to represent the different quadrants. How can I change the lower bound of the index of the array? Is that possible? if not I guess I can do some arithmetic to map the -x or -y numbers to each arrays natural numbers, I am hoping there is another solution though.

I also thought about just having the origin in the middle of my array, but the array grows at runtime, so I would constantly have to shift the contents around to find the new middle. This seems more confusing.

Am I going about this correctly? Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are probably overthinking the problem you have. Based on what you've posted, you need to know:

- What quadrant is a given point in on the cartesian plane?

I would envision a solution something like this:

```
enum CartesianQuadrant {
  None = 0, 
  I,
  II,
  III,
  IV,    
}

struct Point {
  public readonly double X;
  public readonly double Y;
  public readonly CartesianQuadrant Quadrant;

  public Point(double x, double y) {
      X = x; 
      Y = y; 
      Quadrant = x == 0 || y == 0 ? CartesianQuadrant.None :
                 x > 0 ? y > 0 ? CartesianQuadrant.I : CartesianQuadrant.IV :
                 y > 0 ? CartesianQuadrant.II : CartesianQuadrant.III;
  }
}
```

Then when you initialize a `Point`, `Point.Quadrant` will have the quadrant the coordinates are in. You could then have a `Point[]` or `IList<Point>`, or whichever collection would suit your needs.

Example of usage:

```
  var p1 = new Point(3.0, 2.0); // p1.Quadrant == CartesianQuadrant.I
  var p2 = new Point(-3.0, 2.0); // p2.Quadrant == CartesianQuadrant.II
  var p3 = new Point(-3.0, -2.0); // p2.Quadrant == CartesianQuadrant.III
  var p4 = new Point(3.0, -2.0); // p2.Quadrant == CartesianQuadrant.IV
  var pnone1 = new Point(0.0, 2.0); // p2.Quadrant == CartesianQuadrant.None
  var pnone2 = new Point(2.0, 0.0); // p2.Quadrant == CartesianQuadrant.None
  var pnone3 = new Point(0.0, 2.0); // p2.Quadrant == CartesianQuadrant.None
```

Comment: Yes, the coordinates of the objects do the job. There is no need to represent the Cartesian plane in code.

Comment: Now, to generalize to n-dimensions! (just kidding...)

Comment: Comments: (1) It would be preferrable to have `None` the zeroth enum value. (2) In `Point`, the `Quadrant` member could be a property whose `get` accessor calculates the result from the `X` and `Y` fields. (3) Why does your constructor chain `:this()` when there are no fields (not even generated fields) lacking assignment in the constructor body?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen (1) Agreed (2) Implementation detail, interface `IPoint` and implement with a lazy and eager version, would need to make sure that the property wouldn't recalculate every time it was accessed (3) Force of habit with structs, my initial writeup was without a compiler and I confirmed that it compiles without `this()` chained

Comment: Good. After you agreed to my (1), the value `default(Point)`, also known as `new Point()`, is no longer "corrupt" (since the origin (0.0, 0.0) is in `None` quadrant).